# retrieve value from taxonomy page

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm using ACF and I have a color picker field `the_field('marker)` in taxonomy page `project-cat` to let client to select color for each category. I want to display each category color for related posts as well.

This code shows how I display color for each category which is fine:

```
 <?php

                  $terms = get_terms( 'project-cat' );
                // var_dump($terms);

                  if ( ! empty( $terms ) && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ){
                      foreach ( $terms as $term ) {


                          ?>
                              <li>
                                <input id="category_<?php echo $term->term_id; ?>" type="checkbox" name="categories" value="<?php echo $term->term_id; ?>" checked="checked" disabled>
                                <label for="category_<?php echo $term->term_id; ?>">
                                    <div class="catCircle" style="background-color:<?php $marker = get_field('marker', $term->taxonomy . '_' . $term->term_id); echo $marker; ?>"></div>
                                    <?php echo $term->name; ?>
                                </label>
                              </li>

                          <?php
                      }

                      ?>
                    <?php
                      }

                      ?>
```

And this is my array for posts :

```
  <?php 


       $args = array(
          'post_type'      => 'project',
          'posts_per_page' => -1,


        );


      $posts_array = get_posts($args); 
       foreach($posts_array as $post){
        $post=(array)$post;
        $location = get_field('google_map',$post['ID']);
     $term = get_terms( 'project-cat' );

          $array[] = array(
                          'title' => $post['post_title'],
                          'subtitle' => get_field('status',$post['ID']),
                          'catColor' => get_field('marker', $term->taxonomy . '_' . $term->term_id),
                          'catID' => get_field('taxo',$post['ID']),
                          'lat' => $location['lat'],
                          'lng' => $location['lng'],
                          'url' =>get_permalink($post['ID']),
              );
       }
          ?>
```

This code displays one of my category colors for all posts. 
eg: category A , selected color is pink, all posts shows pink color.

if anyone could help me with correcting the query would be appreciated.

Comment: `$term = get_terms( 'project-cat' );` will get you an array in `$term`. Therefore, `$term->taxonomy . '_' . $term->term_id` won't work. Check whether you have any terms, than use the first term returned from `get_terms`.

Comment: could you please share the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go for something like this, having a default color (in my example #ff0000) and then overriding that with the color of the first category of the post. Notice that I'm using wp_get_post_terms - I suppose that is what you want, not get_terms (which will always get ALL the terms, not just those that are selected for the individual post).

```
$terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post['ID'], 'project-cat' );
$catColor = "#ff0000";
if(is_array($terms) && count($terms)) {
    if($newColor = get_field('marker', $terms[0]->taxonomy . '_' . $terms[0]->term_id)) {
        $catColor = $newColor;
    }
}
$array[] = array(
    'title' => $post['post_title'],
    'subtitle' => get_field('status',$post['ID']),
    'catColor' => $catColor,
    'catID' => get_field('taxo',$post['ID']),
    'lat' => $location['lat'],
    'lng' => $location['lng'],
    'url' =>get_permalink($post['ID']),
);
```